# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UserDoc | QuerySelector<UserDoc> | undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have an Area Document

```
// An interface that descripbe the properties
// that a Area document has
interface AreaDoc extends mongoose.Document {
  code: string;
  description: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  createdBy: UserDoc;
  createdAt: Date;
  modifiedAt: Date;
}
```

Trying to use createdBy (interface UserDoc extends mongoose.Document) to find an area.

[image]

I know that this issue is because the  const createdBy = req.currentUser!.id; returns a string value.

Any idea how i can resolve this

Comment: can you try declaring this variable like this const createdBy:any

Comment: Thanks @Anku. This worked as expected. Appreciate your help :)